# LWC JavaScript: Can't Add a Property to Objects While Looping through an Array of Those Objects

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, loop, object, array

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects and add a property to each that meets certain criteria.

Here's the snippet:

```
onRecordEditFormLoad(event)
{    
    let tempFieldWrapperArray = this.fieldSetWrapper.fieldWrappers.map(element => element);
    //console.log('onRecordEditFormLoad running: tempFieldWrapperArray',JSON.stringify(tempFieldWrapperArray));

    let tempInputFieldArray = [];
    this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(inputField => { 
        tempInputFieldArray.push({"fieldName":inputField.fieldName , "value":inputField.value});
    });
    console.log('onRecordEditFormLoad running: tempInputFieldArray',JSON.stringify(tempInputFieldArray));

    tempFieldWrapperArray.forEach(fieldWrapper => {
        let inputField = tempInputFieldArray.find(inputField => inputField.fieldName === fieldWrapper.fieldAPIName);
        console.log('onRecordEditFormLoad running: tempFieldWrapperArray: inputField',JSON.stringify(inputField)); 
        if(inputField){
            console.log('inputField.value',inputField.value);
            console.log('fieldWrapper',fieldWrapper);
            fieldWrapper.value = inputField.value;
        }
    });
    console.log('onRecordEditFormLoad running: tempFieldWrapperArray',JSON.stringify(tempFieldWrapperArray)); 
}
```

The code stops running where it adds the property: `fieldWrapper.value = inputField.value;`

The `fieldWrapper` object and `inputField.value` are valid and log. If I comment out `fieldWrapper.value = inputField.value`, the rest of the code runs.

Comment: What error do you get in the browser console when the offending code is executed?

Comment: No error. The code just stops running passed that line.

Comment: (See sfdcfox's answer; basically results from wire and imperative class are frozen (using [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or similar), which means you need to clone the objects before you can modify the clones.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming that this came from a server call, you need to copy the objects entirely:

```
let tempFieldWrapperArray = this.fieldSetWrapper.fieldWrappers.map(element => ({...element}));
```

Or:

```
let tempFieldWrapperArray = this.fieldSetWrapper.fieldWrappers.map(element => Object.assign({},element));
```

This is because the entire response is locked behind a [ReadOnlyMembrane](https://github.com/salesforce/observable-membrane) that prevents modification so that the cache can't be corrupted by references.

By copying the elements using the spread operator (...), or Object.assign into a new object, you will remove the read-only properties of all top-level elements.

Comment: could you please update your answer to indicate that the objects obtained from the server are "frozen" and are therefore immutable. At that point the cloning then makes absolute sense. I would expect this is handled via use of Object.freeze.

Comment: @PhilW Good point.

Comment: Nice. How about adding a reference to https://github.com/salesforce/observable-membrane which includes a section on read-only membranes and appears to be part of the Salesforce infrastructure (note that Kevin Hill contributed).

Answer (score 2):

```
let tempFieldWrapperArray = this.fieldSetWrapper.fieldWrappers.map(element => element);
```

Here, you are just assigning new memory location to array variable. But, Javascript allocates separate memory for main array and the elements inside it (if they are objects).

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_data_flow):

> A non-primitive value (like an object or array) passed to a component
> is read-only. The component cannot change the content of the object or
> array. If the component tries to change the content, you see an error
> in the browser console. To mutate the data, make a shallow copy of the
> objects you want to mutate.

So, the object returned directly or in an array will be in immutable/frozen state. You will see debug logs in console when you [Enable Debug Mode for Lightning Components](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_debug_mode.htm&type=5)

You need to return new copy for each object inside array as each one is immutable.

```
tempFieldWrapperArray = tempFieldWrapperArray.map(fieldWrapper => {
    fieldWrapper = {...fieldWrapper};
    -- code --
        fieldWrapper.value = inputField.value;
    
    return fieldWrapper;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the issue clearly - if I copy/paste the two statements you have I CAN run them successfully.

Comment: you cannot if arr is api variable and being passed down to it

Comment: I suggest you clarify you mean @api annotated. Yes, this is true again because the LWC framework ensures such values are frozen.

Comment: @PhilW yea, took the code line directly, hope explanation is clear now

Comment: Can you add explanation as to why the objects in the array are immutable please.

Comment: Basically add something like "Objects received in an LWC either through an @api property or from a wire or imperative call to the server are immutable (likely using Object.freeze)."